# Proof for Existence of a set of cartesian products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is an exercise from the textbook Elements of Set Theory by Enderton.

**Exercise**:

a) Assume $A$ and $B$ are given sets, and show that there exists a set $C$ such that for any $y$,

$$
y\in C \iff y = \{x\}\times B \text{ for some } x \in A.
$$

In other words, show that $$\{\{x\}\times B \mid x\in A\}$$ is a set.

**My process**:

So, $C$ must be a collection of sets each of which is a collection of ordered pairs of the form $(x,b)$ for some $b\in B$.

From an earlier exercise, we have the following result:

For any $x,y\in D$, $(x,y)\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(D)).$

I jump over a few steps here but basically we can show $A \times B \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)).$

This should give us that any $t\in \{x\}\times B \implies t\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{x\}\cup B))$ and so we get $\{x\}\times B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{x\}\cup B)))$ which we know exists.

So the following set should exist:

$$
F = \{w\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{x\}\cup B))) \mid w = \{(x,b)\mid b\in B\} \text{ and } x \in A\}.
$$

Is any of this correct?
My problem is how do I even formally write all of this? What does $x$ belong to when I look at the set $\{x\}\times B$? I am not even sure I am on the right path. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the axiom schema of separation:

$(\forall A)(\forall B)(\exists C)(\forall y)(y\in C\iff y\in D \land (y=\{x\}\times B \land (\exists x)(x\in A))$

$D$ as we shall see is $PP(A\cup B)$

The proof strategy is to show that if the ordered pair $<x,z>, x\in A\land z\in B$ exists then it belongs to the bigger set $D$ in the axiom schema.

Thus:
$<x,z>=\{\{x\},\{x,z\}\}$

by definition of ordered pairs.

$\{x\}\in PA\iff \{x\}\subseteq A$
by powerset axiom.

$\{x,z\}\in P(A\cup B)$ by pairing, union and power axioms.

Thus:
$\{\{x,\},\{x,z\}\}\in PP(A\cup B)$

Now that we have shown that $<x,z>$ belongs to the greater set $PP(A\cup B)$ the set exists by axiom schema of separation.

And is unique by extensionality.

And we can use set builder notation to construct it.